# Qt - two signals and modal dialog window

Tags: qt, signals, modal-dialog, slot

I have a `QDialog` based class.

I have one `QEditLine *editLine` and `QButton *button`.

I use `clicked()` signal of button. And `editingFinished()` signal of editLine.

When I change the text in the editLine and press the button firstly `editingFinished()` signal is emitted. In the slot method I call `QMessageBox::question()`.
After that I can't receive `clicked()` signal of my button.

I tried to use `Qt::QueuedConnection` for connect method, but it does not help.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the event loop for the message box is blocking the main event loop so your button's signal is not emitted. But how do you plan to click the button anyway if you have a modal dialog open?

Comment: Button looks like clicked. And when modal dialog is closed it still looks pressed. I would like to process clicked() signal after modal dialog is closed. So, I should somehow postpone emiting of clicked() signal, until modal dialog is closed...or I could check whether the button is pressed after modal dialog is closed. But that is ugly :(

Comment: Can you post at least partial code? I'd say that the signal should still be emitted, simply after the dialog is closed. Is the connect() call where you connect the button's signal returning without errors?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    appPath = QApplication::applicationDirPath();

    connect(pButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(build()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    connect(pLineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(pathChanged()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void Window::pathChanged()
{
    QString path = pLineEdit->text();

    if(createPath(path))
        updatePath(path);
}

bool Window::createPath(QString path)
{
    if(!QDir(path).exists())
    {
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
        reply = QMessageBox::question(this, tr("Folder is not exist"), "Folder " + path + " is not exist. Do you want to create it?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
        if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
        {
             QDir dir;
             dir.mkpath(path);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

class Window : public QDialog, public Ui::GLConverterDialogUI
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Window(void);
    ......
}
```

Comment: Did it fail the same way with `Qt::DirectConnection`? Since the objects live in the main thread, there is basically no need for `Qt::QueuedConnection`. Another thing you can do, is actually put a break-point in the qt sources where the `clicked()` signal is emitted and see how it is dispatched, since I'm not sure why is it failing.

Comment: Yes behavior with Qt::DirectConnection is the same. I will try to play with clicked().

Comment: If you remove the call to message box, does it get better? Since without the second event loop i don't see what else could mess things up.

Comment: Yes. I have just tried to comment `reply = QMessageBox::question(...` and instead set `reply = QMessageBox::Yes`. In this case both `pathChanged()` and `build()` are called.

Comment: You can try this [link](http://flei.ho.ua/DialogSignal.zip) small example to reproduce my problem.

Comment: clicked() is emitted in the mouseReleaseEvent() of QAbstractButton. But after a message box is shown, the button remains pressed, so mouseReleaseEvent() is not called....

Comment: Hmm, ok this is getting interresting, maybe it's eaten by the modal dialogs event loop, however i'm not sure, if that is possible. Do you consider making the dialog non-modal?

Comment: Actually, firstly user should make a choice and after that I need to call my code for a clicked event. That's why modal dialog is a solution to postpone calling of a code for clicked event.

Comment: Can't you show the dialog about the path creation in the `clicked()` signal handling slot and just return if user cancels? That way you would need only one signal handler?

Comment: Yes, this will solve the problem. But behavior of application will be a little different. And I have another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in another application. I use some library. I guess that this library use pressed() signal of QAbstractButton instead of clicked(). And when I call `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()` after button is pressed it seems that `mouseReleaseEvent()` is also not called. So after closing of dialog button is still pressed and I have to send MouseButtonRealese event manually.
Maybe I should call dialog with some special parameters?

Comment: When I have time, I'll debug your example, not sure where the `mouseReleaseEvent()` disappears.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please take a look to this example: [link](http://flei.ho.ua/DialogSignal2.zip) Here I removed editingFinished() signal. But the problem is the same.